# How to figure out which significant works in Esperanto are Public Domain by now?

Tags: books

I would like to be able to read and work with newly Public Domain Esperanto works. How can I best try to retrieve information about which works were released when and as such when they are in the public domain?

Comment: Vi povas trovi kelkajn verkojn (ne nepre gravajn aŭ aparte elstarajn) ĉi tie: https://www.gutenberg.org/browse/languages/eo

Comment: @das-g You are right that this might be hard to answer, but I think now it is no longer opinion based so I think it could probably be reopened

Comment: As a contributor and user of it, I recommend visiting Vikifontaro [eo.wikisource.org](http://eo.wikisource.org). This is a Wikimedia project (like Wikipedia), but for public domain Esperanto works. It’s a project where you can find old books, read them and also contribute to make public domain works more accessible for everyone. (We really need some help).